# Updating historical data by joining another table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table A(simplified version below) that is updated with a daily scheduled query. Last week we added a new column - ad_number - to the table. Going forward, ad_number will be populated with data. However, I would like to pull the historical data from last year, for this column.

```
Event_date (dimension)
App_id (dimension)
Country (dimension)
Ad_network (dimension)
Total_revenue (metric)
Ad_number (metric)
```

Because of the large data volume, I've created a separate table B with the same dimensions and ad_number, to pull from the source table indicated in the scheduled query. I plan on joining this into Table A. Any tips on how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know what the value is for last year, if the column wasn't in the data?

You can add a fixed value -- such as `NULL`:

```
select Event_date, App_id, Country, Ad_network, Total_revenue, Ad_number,
      null as ad_number
from b;
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for not being clear. I've edited the post. 

The scheduled query pulls from another source table C and updates table A daily. I pulled the historical data into table B from table C. Hope this helps. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

As you have the historical data in another table (Table B), the simplest solution for populating the historical data on Table A would be using a SQL script similar to:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.tableA` AS TableA
SET TableA.field_to_update = TableB.field_to_update
FROM (
select unique_identifier, field_to_update from `project.dataset.tableB`
) TableB
WHERE TableA.unique_identifier = TableB.unique_identifier;
```

Please notice that a unique identifier for the record is needed.